# ContentPresenter - HorizonalAlignment not working

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controls, alignment

I have created a custom control for the simplified usage of `label: control` in forms:

[image]

My problem is that, no matter what is being put into my control content, I am unable to align it, using my template code. The only way it works is  when I put `HorizontalAlignment="Right"` into the `TextBox` control directly:

```
<local:ControlEntry Label="Enter something">

    <!--  I don't like having HorizontalAlignment here!  -->
    <TextBox Height="20" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />

</local:ControlEntry>
```

However, I would rather want to do that behind the scenes in my control template.

I'm talking about this particular XAML code:

```
<Border x:Name="Container"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        Grid.Column="1">

    <ContentPresenter Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Container}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />

</Border>
```

First, I stretch the `HorizontalAlignment`, so what it would fill the width of the grid column cell, then I'm trying to apply the `Right` `HorizontalAlignment` on the `ContentPresenter`. Unfortunately, no effect is visible.

Full control code:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ControlLine}">

    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ControlLine}">

                <!-- Create bottom content border -->
                <Border BorderBrush="#000" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0.5">

                    <StackPanel>

                        <Grid>

                            <!--  Label -> Control  -->
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <!--  Label  -->
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                                       Margin="0,12,15,12"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       Text="{Binding Label, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                       TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" />

                            <!--  Display content  -->
                            <Border x:Name="Container"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                    Grid.Column="1">

                                <ContentPresenter Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Container}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />

                            </Border>

                        </Grid>

                        <!--  Description  -->
                        <TextBlock Text="The control description" />

                    </StackPanel>

                </Border>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

</Style>
```

How can I properly keep the width stretched and at the same time align the content of `ContentPresenter` to right?

Comment: Try `HorizontalContentAlignment` property

Comment: If you want to align the content (TextBlock) to the right, what element do you want to stretch?

Comment: @mm8 First, what I want is having the `ContentPresenter` full width of the grid cell (hence the `ActualWidth` binding) then I want to align the `ContentPresenter` content (which is `TextBox` in this case) to the right (which is inside second grid column). The `TextBlock` which is in the first grid column, I want to stay default.

Comment: Get rid of that `StackPanel` parent in there....if I'm understanding your intent correctly that is.

Comment: @ChrisW. Thanks, but that didn't made any difference.

Comment: I must be misreading something then, if you show me what your expected result is we'll get you sorted. Though possibly tomorrow since I'm leaving for the day soon. :)

Comment: @ChrisW. Like I said, I want full width (grid column width) `ContentPresenter` which content is aligned right.